# Как вставить фрагмент jsf страницы в <IFrame/>?

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsf

Решаемая задача, есть legacy с бэкэндом на jsf. 
Мне нужно перейти на Spring  +  reactJS

Дело в том, что это ресурсоемкая задача, поэтому было решено, что пока переделывать приложение только частично, для первой версии. То есть, в старой версии есть jsf страница, в которой отрисовывается меню, кнопки и таблица, допустим со списком сотрудников.

Мне нужно, в свою новую версию приложения вставить старую jsf страничку, обрезав лишнее и оставив только таблицу.

Таким образом я смог бы создать компонент, который каким-то образом получал бы такие jsf, отрезал бы меню и кнопки и отрисовывал бы таблицу, например в iframe. Реализуема ли эта задача, в сторону каких технологий стоило бы посмотреть подскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: Недостаточно информации: опишите структуру проекта и решаемую задачу (а не своё решение).

Comment: поправил комментарий